# UIView Frame Size Didn't Change UIImageView Placed inside it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, cgrectmake

I'm making a picture in a frame and then user can resize the frame size in runtime. For this purpose I've made a custom `UIView` in my main `UIViewController` and inside this `UIView` I've placed 2 `UIImageView`. In Document Outline Pane of xCode it's hierarchy is:

> View 
> |--ImageView 
> |--ImageView

I'm using this line of code to change size of `UIView` under different conditions it'll resize accordingly:

```
self.imageObject.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageObject.frame.origin.x , 
                                    self.imageObject.frame.origin.y, 
                                    200, 
                                    200);
```

**imageObject** is my `UIView`. When I run it the size of the `UIView` changes but `UIImageView` size remains the same. I've also tried doing the same for my `UIImageView` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try this. CGRect frameA=self.imageObject.frame;
frameA=CGRectMake(self.imageObject.frame.origin.x ,self.imageObject.frame.origin.y, 200, 200);
self.imageObject.frame = frameA;
[self.imageObject.frame setClipsToBounds:YES];
CGRect frameB=CGRectMake(0 ,0, frameA.size.Width, frameA.size.Height);
[imageView setFrame:frameB];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also Try This :-

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,imageObject.frame.size.width, imageObject.frame.size.height);
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.imageShw.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: but there is problem  when i do AutoResizinMask  its not work then  what i do   pls.

Comment: imageShw.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES You Also need To  do That for AutoResizinmask  then its Work Perfecttally

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've played with autoresizing and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                             0,
                             imageObject.frame.size.width, 
                             imageObject.frame.size.height);
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | 
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: but there is a probleam

Comment: Don't understand. When you created the internal UIImageView, did you set the autoresizingMask property?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've played with autoresizing and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

First You can try,

```
self.imageObject.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Otherwise to get the subviews to resize, you can add autoresizing mask to the subviews, to the two imageviews in your case:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Check  [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW58) for more details.

Comment: I've set the autoresizesSubviews to YES but this didn't work. Doesn't autoresizingMask set the BOOL automatically to YES?